# Image uploading on android

Tags: android, image, url, connection

I am in a strange problem right now.
I've been trying to upload an image from my android app to the server, **however it works fine when i am using wifi connection but when i am on GPRS the application just keeps on processing for an infinite amount of time**. Below is the code:

```
    try
    {
        Log.i(TAG,"publishFileToServer Called...");
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath) );
        URL url = new URL(urlServer);
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        Log.i(TAG,"publishFileToServer Called... 1");
        // Allow Inputs & Outputs
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        Log.i(TAG,"publishFileToServer Called... 2");
        // Enable POST method
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
        Log.i(TAG,"publishFileToServer Called...3");
        outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + filePath +"\"" + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        Log.i(TAG,"publishFileToServer Called...4");
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        Log.i(TAG,"publishFileToServer Called...5");
        // Read file
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        Log.i(TAG,"publishFileToServer Called...6");
        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }
        Log.i(TAG,"publishFileToServer Called...7");
        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
        Log.i(TAG,"publishFileToServer Called...8");
        // Responses from the server (code and message)
        int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        Log.i(TAG,"publishFileToServer: ServerResponseCode = "+serverResponseCode);
        String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
        Log.i(TAG,"publishFileToServer: ServerResponseMessage = "+serverResponseMessage);
        Log.i(TAG,"publishFileToServer Called...9");
        fileInputStream.close();
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        Log.i(TAG,"publishFileToServer Called...10");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e(TAG,"publishFileToServer: "+ex.getMessage());
    }
```

It's noticeable that i use this same code to upload a text file an it works fine even on GPRS, i've tried to narrow it down and my application goes into the problem right before the getResponse() method when I am uploading an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem went away after a re-install of the sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this from inside an activity?

Use a service and put it in an AsyncTask

With wifi, there is little to no latency. With the cell network, there is plenty of latency, so your request is most likely blocking the ui thread.

Comment: I am using a processDialog and this code is infact in a separate thread. When it comes to getResponse() it just hangs there in the LogCat. Everything else in the emulator works fine if i click on home etc, but if i go back into the application it's still processing and in the LogCat the last message i see from the app is just above the getResponse() method.